# How to filter by different Places on Google Maps Api Search

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

So, I'm making a website where I have to insert a map, search box (input) and dropdown list.

```
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center: pyrmont,
  zoom: 15
});

var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
};
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var place = results[i];
  createMarker(results[i]);
}
}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here is the javascript code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div id="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="pac-input" type="text" class="form-control"                                      placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i   class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- .input -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="dropdown" >
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Pick a location
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="type-selector">
                        <li id="changetype-restaurant" ><a value="restaurant" id="changetype-restaurant" href="#" >Restaurant</a></li>
                        <li id="changetype-cafe"><a value="cafe" id="changetype-cafe" href="#"Cafe</a></li>
                        <li id="changetype-movie_theater"><a value="movie_theater" id="changetype-movie_theater" href="#">Movie theater</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- .dropdown -->
            </div>
```

Here's the html code.

The dropdown list needs to contain 3 choices; if the user wants to search for restaurants then he clicks on restaurants and types in the search box and it lists results for that. I need to use place types for this but I don't know how to implement all that.

So far I made the map and I can list all the results, but I don't know how to list only the results for the item that was picked in the dropdown list. I don't know how to connect the dropdown to the input search box.